# positionYOffset and scrollTop on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, mobile-website

Is there any solution to get the window.positionYOffset or window.scrollTop on mobile browsers?Now it returns 0.
Everything works OK in all browsers, except the mobile ones.
Any tips?
I searched other threads on this topic but there is no viable option which worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you trying to achieve. Have you tried window.offset.top?

Comment: i need the current distance from the top of the page to the place the user is currently scrolled, so i can display an alert exactly at this position

Comment: window.offset.top does not return anything (not even 0). Can you be more specific about how it can be used?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If yes, try this `alert($('div').first().offset().top);`

Comment: I am using jquery, but your alert will give me the vertical offset for a specific element from DOM (in your example, the first div). I need to know the offset of the users' scroll( how much did the user scrolled down from  the top of the page.). I don't want to show him an alert, or to display an alert at that offset. I want for instance, when he presses a button, an alert to be shown right in the middle of the portion of the page that he is currently viewing. Thanks

Comment: In this case I would use css. `div { position: fixed; height: 100px; top: calc(50% - 50px); // minus half height left: 0; }`

Comment: Does it? I had issues only with `width: calc()` for androids, but position fixed works. Which phone you are using to test?

Comment: I don't know how, but it works for me and ios5, and androids :) try this [link](http://firelitdesign.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/floating-section-scrolls-with-page-html.html)